# Bcrypt error in simple Node router

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I have a route for creating users in Node/Express. I am getting a weird error about a method on the model not existing.

Here is the model for users:

```
'use strict'; 

const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'); 

mongoose.Promsie = global.Promise; 

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }, 
    password: { type: String, required: true }, 
    email: { type: String, required: true }, 
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    families: [
        {
            family_key: { type: String, required: true }, 
            family_name: { type: String }
        }
    ]
}); 

UserSchema.methods.apiRepr = function() {
    return {
        id: this._id,
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
        username: this.username,
        email: this.email, 
        families: this.families 
    }; 
}; 

UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hash(password, 10); 
}

UserSchema.methods.validatePassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password); 
}

const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema); 

module.exports = { User };
```

Not particularly complicated. BUT, my the route is having trouble with the "hashPassword" method. When I try to use this route, I get an error that says "TypeError: User.hashPassword is not a function"

Here is the route (the issue is close to the bottom):

```
router.post('/', jsonParser, (req, res) => {

    // checking that required fields are present

    const requiredFields = ['username', 'password', 'email']; 
    const missingField = requiredFields.find(field => !(field in req.body));

    if(missingField) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            code: 422, 
            reason: 'Validation Error', 
            message: 'Missing field', 
            location: missingField
        });
    }

    // checking the format of string fields

    const stringFields = ['username', 'password', 'email', 'lastname', 'firstname']; 
    const nonStringField = stringFields.find(
        field => field in req.body && typeof req.body[field] !== 'string'
    ); 

    if (nonStringField) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            code: 422, 
            reason: 'Validation Error', 
            message: 'Incorrect field type: expected string', 
            location: nonStringField
        }); 
    }

    // checking the trimming on fields

    const trimmedFields = ['username', 'password', 'email']; 
    const nonTrimmedField = trimmedFields.find(
        field => req.body[field].trim() !== req.body[field]
    ); 

    if (nonTrimmedField) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            code: 422, 
            reason: 'Validation Error', 
            message: 'Cannot start or end with whitespace', 
            location: nonTrimmedField
        }); 
    }

    // checking length of fields with required length

    const sizedFields = {
        username: { min: 1 }, 
        password: { min: 10, max: 72 }
    };
    const tooSmallField = Object.keys(sizedFields).find(field => 
        'min' in sizedFields[field] &&
        req.body[field].trim().length < sizedFields[field].min
    );
    const tooLargeField = Object.keys(sizedFields).find(field => 
        'max' in sizedFields[field] &&
        req.body[field].trim().length > sizedFields[field].max
    ); 

    if (tooSmallField || tooLargeField) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            code: 422, 
            reason: 'Validation Error', 
            message: tooSmallField
            ? `Must be at least ${sizedFields[tooSmallField].min} characters long`
            : `Must be at most ${sizedFields[tooLargeField].max} characters long`,
            location: tooSmallField || tooLargeField
        }); 
    }

    // creating the user

    let { username, firstname, lastname, families, email, password } = req.body; 
    return User.find({ username })
        .count()
        .then(count => {
            if(count > 0) {
                return Promise.reject({
                    code: 422, 
                    reason: 'Validation Error', 
                    message: 'Username already taken', 
                    location: 'username'
                }); 
            }
            return User.hashPassword(password); 
        })
        .then(hash => {
            return User.create({ username, firstname, lastname, families, email, password: hash })
        })
        .then(user => {
            return res.status(201).json(user.apiRepr()); 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
            res.status(500).json({ code: 500, message: 'Internal server error'})
        })
})
```

It does not like the return User.hashPassword(password) part. Any thoughts about what is causing this? I'm copying from a working app. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The issue appears to be with the model? It won't let me run any of the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods in node.js can not be used directly using the SchemaName you need to create an object of the schema name and then use the methods of the schema.

Ex:

```
var AnimalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
  , type: String
});

AnimalSchema.methods.findSimilarType = function findSimilarType (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
};

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', AnimalSchema);
var dog = new Animal({ name: 'Rover', type: 'dog' });

dog.findSimilarType(function (err, dogs) {
  if (err) return ...
  dogs.forEach(..);
})
```

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html

In your code you are trying to access the methods from the model.
Instantiate the model then use the methods.

If need use like the way you are using in the code try using function instead of methods.

```
module.exports.funtionName = function(/*function params*/){
//function body here 

};
```

Comment: I actually lifted this code from several earlier projects. This code works: 

UserSchema.methods.validatePassword = function (password){
  return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

UserSchema.statics.hashPassword = function (password){
  return bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
};

const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = {User};

...then in the router....

return User.hashPassword(password)

I have no idea why it works there and not here

Comment: In this code you have added in comment, you are using statics not methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: That ^ was the answer. Been at that for 3 hours man ha. Thank you so much!